# Jquery returning some unwanted data in Ajax success

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I have a Ajax method like this using Jquery.

```
 function add_item()
 {
 item_name=$("#item_names").val()
 var pars = item_name;
 $.ajax({
            url: "/billing/add_bill_detail",
            type: "get",
            dataType: "html",
            data: {"pars" : pars},
            success: function(returnData){
            alert(returnData)
            $("#aaa").append(returnData).html;
            }
        });
```

}

if i puts alert for the returnData its returning with some extra data. Like as follows.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>SamplePro</title>

 <script src="/javascripts/jquery.js?1363935663" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="/javascripts/jquery_ujs.js?1363935663" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="/javascripts/application.js?1362549711" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="/javascripts/jquery.js?1363935663" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="/javascripts/application.js?1362549711" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

<tr class="tablehead">
 <td>
BAB-001
</td>
 <td>
BABY MASK 1
</td>
 <td>
 </td>
 <td>
     <input id="tax_rule_tax_rule" name="tax_rule[tax_rule]" size="30" type="text" value="sfdsf" />
 </td>
 </tr>
 </br>


</body>
</html>
```

But the file add_bill_detail actutall contain

```
 <% if from != "reload" %>
 <tr class="tablehead">
 <td>
 <%=from ? item_details.item.item_code : ""%>
 </td>
  <td>
   <%=from ? item_details.item.name : ""%>
  </td>
 <td>
 </td>
   <td>
    <%= text_field 'tax_rule', 'tax_rule',:value => "sfdsf" %>
     </td>
  </tr>
 <%end%>
 </br>
```

Please help me to remove the unwanted Data. Thanks in Advance..

Updated Question:

i have added the follwoing scripts

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

My actual problem because of this is..

[image]

here all the values from the add_bill_detail is going under one column. it should go to 4 columns.
[image]

updated add_bill_detail code..

```
 <table>
 <tr class="tablehead">
 <td>
 <%=from ? item_details.item.item_code : ""%>
 </td>
 <td>
 <%=from ? item_details.item.name : ""%>
 </td>
 <td>
 </td>
 <td>
    <%= text_field 'tax_rule', 'tax_rule',:value => "sfdsf" %>
</td>
<td>
    <%= text_field 'tax_rule', 'tax_rule2',:value => "vvvv" %>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: inside `add_bill_detail` just output the table code not html and other code..

Comment: @DipeshParmar i am not getting. Please post as a answer.

Comment: Does your script include any kind of header and footer code..?

Comment: yes. i have updated my question. with that

Comment: Try alerting `alert($(returnData).find('tr.tablehead'));` and see what its alerting..also do not add jQuery twice...

Comment: Best way to remove unwanted data is not to have it there in the first place.

Comment: What do you want it to look like?  What's ***unwanted Data***?  Why do you have multiple `jquery.js?<num>` and `application.js?<num>` files?  Have you ever attempted to format your ruby/php code?  It's a basic table it and it looks almost unreadable - scratch that - I  really don't want to read it.

Comment: @vol7ron hi. if i am removing any .js autocomplete is not working

Comment: You should be able to get rid of the last two w/o it affecting anything.  Of course I don't realllly know what the server is returning in those files as you have not given a working demo

Comment: i have updated my actual problem. please check and help me

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the `<tr class="tablehead">` tags, simply use the [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method.

`alert($(returnData).filter('tr.tablehead').html())` should work!

**EDIT:** You are using a `tr` tag without the parent `table` tag. Hence, they get ignored in rendered HTML by the browser, browser strips off the `tr` tags and displays only the text. As jquery works on rendered html its behavior is the same.

**Fix:** Wrap your `tr` tags with the parent `table` tags and you should be good to go.

what I mean by that is:

```
<table>
    <tr class="tablehead">
     <td>
    BAB-001
    </td>
     <td>
    BABY MASK 1
    </td>
     <td>
     </td>
     <td>
         <input id="tax_rule_tax_rule" name="tax_rule[tax_rule]" size="30" type="text" value="sfdsf" />
     </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

Notice the `table` tag wrapping your `tr` tag.

**How to avoid this problem in future?**

Always check what your rendered HTML looks like using a tool like [Inspect Element](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/elements) in Chrome and [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) in firefox. If you'll do that for your table you'll notice that the tr tags get stripped by the browser.

Comment: its giving error as follows    returnData.find is not a function

alert(returnData.find('tablehead').html())

Comment: @poojaagarwal Okay! I was wrong. I assumed you had the returnData as a jquery object. Try using `alert($(returnData).filter('.tablehead').html())`

Comment: its giving alert as undefined.

Comment: @poojaagarwal I can't find any reason why that would happen. Are you sure you using `.filter` method, and the returnData contains what you said it contains in the question?

Comment: i am sure. i am using .filter and returnData contains the same

Comment: @poojaagarwal Ah! Finally figured it out. You got to wrap your `tr` tag with the `table` tags.

Comment: sorry for asking again. i dont know how to do. please help me with code

Comment: @poojaagarwal I updated your table definition! Do you get it now?

Comment: nooo. its giving wrong result only. i updated my question with the output

Comment: @poojaagarwal Are you now using the table tag? I still don't see that edited in the question. And please be a little descriptive about the errors "`nooo. its giving wrong result only.`" wouldn't really help me decipher the problem.

Comment: sorry Aneesh Dogra. I updated the question with screenshot. its still appending under one column.